# How to generate UIUD using button without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTbzr.png)

here is my javascript on how im generating the UIUD
and

Regenerate Secret
are my HMTL.
I know to not refresh the whole page I need a type='button' in the button element, but when i add that, i am not loading up anything using my onClick. I really don't understand why adding type= button would break this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: <input id="generated_secret_text" class="awareid_user_input" type="text" readonly="true"/>
<button id="generateUUID" onclick="onClick()">Regenerate Secret</button>
here are my html without button type

Comment: Add details in the question not on comments. Anyway a button with no type is of type submit by default so it will submit the form refreshing the page. There are several ways to prevent that including using event.preventDefault() on your handler. But it’s much better to just use type=“button”. The reason you said on why you didn’t use it is not clear

Comment: @DiegoDeVita when i added type='button', the button doesnt do anything ie not creating a new UUID that gets displayed in the textbox.

Comment: there's something wrong somewhere in your code.. because the button type=button can't be the issue. Maybe there's something in your error console showing the details? Anyway I posted an early answer to show what I meant since the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This is too weak as an answer since your problem isn't clear yet. Anyway it's a step to show that the problem lies elsewhere. As you can see that's how a button should behave (while being of type button).

But you should include your javascript as text, instead of picture, if you want it to be included here.

```js
function onClick(event){
  const uuid = generateUUID();
  document.getElementById('status')
    .textContent = `a new UUID:${uuid} was generated!`;
}

function generateUUID(){
  return '12345' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999);
}
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#status{
  border: dashed 2px gray;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="onClick(event);">Generate UUID</button>

<div id="status"></div>
```